# drawing duplicated points in gnuplot with small margin

Tags: gnuplot, duplicates

I'm wondering if there is a way to draw duplicated points in gnuplot without letting them be invisible, putting the point to (X+rand(-0.5;0.5),Y+rand(-0.5;0.5)). So the dot is not placed at X/Y of the previous point but - depending on randomize - a little bit up, down, left or right. Then no dot becomes invisible.

This effect is called "jitter". This is a good example: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/jitter.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add random deviations to a data point, just use the `rand` function:

```
myrand(x) = (x + rand(0) - 0.5)
plot 'data.dat' using (myrand($1)):(myrand($2))
```

`rand(0)` generates a value in the range `[0:1]`.

If you want to plot each point multiple times, you need to iterate as many times:

```
plot for [i=0:4] 'data.dat' using (myrand($1)):(myrand($2))
```

In order to take into account the number of occurences, like shown in your link, one has to trick a bit.

Consider the data file (taken from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/faq/jitter.htm), with the third column holding the number of occurences:

```
1 1 4
1 2 7
1 3 6
2 1 9
2 2 5
2 3 11
3 1 1
3 2 2
3 3 3
4 1 12
4 2 8
4 3 10
```

One way is to extract the maximum number of occurences from the data file and then plot with iterations. In each iteration a point is added, if its number of occurences is higher than the current iteration index. A point is skipped by setting one coordinate to `1/0`:

```
stats 'data.dat' using 3 nooutput
set style line 1 pointtype 6 linecolor -1
myrand(x) = x + 0.3 * (rand(0) - 0.5)
plot for [i=0:int(STATS_max)-1] 'data.dat' \
    using (myrand($1)):(i < $3 ? myrand($2) : 1/0) linestyle 1 notitle
```

That gives (with 4.6.3):

[image]

where I used the additional settings:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'data.png'
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set autoscale fix
set offset 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5
```

Comment: thx a lot for the big help, but can It be done without adding the occurrences column?

Comment: @zoma.saf Yes, of course. That would be the easier way. If you just want to plot each point randomly shifted, just use the first 'script' in my answer. If you want to shift each point, say `5` times, just use cancel the `stats` part, and use `plot for [i=0:4] 'data.dat' using (myrand($1)):(myrand($2))`. If that is what you want, I can add it to the answer.

Comment: got it, didn't know this feature since I'm still new :)

Comment: 2012-09-18 0 7 6
2011-10-05 0 7 0
2012-12-18 0 8 12
2012-09-18 0 8 12
2012-03-15 0 8 5
2012-12-18 0 8 11
2012-09-18 0 8 11
2012-03-15 0 8 5
2011-12-06 3 8 3
2012-12-18 0 8 8
2012-09-18 0 8 8
2012-03-29 0 8 2
2011-12-06 3 8 3
2012-12-18 0 8 8
2012-09-18 0 8 8

sorry another question, how can I make a loop over the data above and the number of iterations is column number 4 ?

Comment: @zoma.saf Uff, hard to say. Do you need the first column, or is it, that 2 is `x`, 3 is `y` and 4 is occurences? In this case, you can just use my last script, but adapt it to use the respective columns. Otherwise you must be more specific about the meaning of each column.